# How to get dynamically generated UI Elements from knockout

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

Given the following:

```
<div id="dashboardViewer" data-bind="foreach: dashboards">
    <div data-bind="foreach: widgets">
        <canvas></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I access the canvas so I can pass that to chart.js while looping through my widgets? It seems I cannot assign it an ID and pull it out using jquery or the DOM utilities, because it's dynamic and not in the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the element, you should create a [custom binding](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html).

Something like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.chartJS = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // This will be called once when the binding is first applied to an element,
        // and again whenever any observables/computeds that are accessed change
        // Update the DOM element based on the supplied values here.

        var data = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());

        // do stuff with the data, the element and any external libraries such as ChartJS here!
    }
};
```

And your HTML would look like this:

```
<div id="dashboardViewer" data-bind="foreach: dashboards">
    <div data-bind="foreach: widgets">
        <canvas data-bind="chartJS: $data"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

That is assuming there is some data in the widget that you would need when working with ChartJS. That's why I passed it to the binding handler as a parameter.